# Easy Movie Texture plays in Unity editor but not on device. What am I missing?

Tags: ios, iphone, unity-game-engine

We're using the Easy Movie Texture asset from the asset store and we are trying to play embedded mp4 files on an iPhone 7 device. It works fine with streaming URLs but once I tried to actually Load() an mp4 file it response very unhelpfully:

[prepareAsset]Error: Item cannot be played
Unknown error 0
MediaPlayerCtrl:OnError(MEDIAPLAYER_ERROR, MEDIAPLAYER_ERROR)

Is there any special gotchas anyone has seen with the difference between playing in editor and on an iOS device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue ended up being the bitrate. Once we encoded the videos with Adobe instead of ffmpeg, it the videos seemed to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.

The error is printed when [asset](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avasset?language=objc).[playable](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avasset/1385974-playable) is false.

It could be an url issue or an unsupported format..

My guess is that the resolution is too high

> iOS: General devices support up to 1920 * 1080.
>
> The latest device is support up to 2560 * 1440.
>
> iPhone 6s Plus supports up to 4k.
>
> https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/10032

Edit: Tested. resolution is indeed my issue here.

Answer (score -1):

I've never used that specific asset pack, but you may want to take a look at the Unity Documentation on Movie Textures, as it may still be relevant even with the asset pack you are using.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MovieTexture.html

Maybe it's worth making sure your video file(s) meet the requirements mentioned in the Unity Documentation and trying to see if that remedies your issue.