# Android: Easy Movie Texture working in editor but not phone

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, google-vr, 360-virtual-reality

I'm having the same issue as [Easy Movie Texture plays in Unity editor but not on device. What am I missing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40142573/easy-movie-texture-plays-in-unity-editor-but-not-on-device-what-am-i-missing) but the solutions mentioned don't seem to work. I'm running my application on an Android device but besides that it's the same problem. I'm using a video converted in VLC using H.264 and with a frame size of 1920x1080. The video I'm using works in the editor but isn't working on the device itself. The end goal is to create a VR 360 Video player using Unity.

Comment: Use Unity's [video Player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41144054/using-new-unity-videoplayer-and-videoclip-api-to-play-video). Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43004339/play-360-stereoscopic-video-with-videoplayer/43006526#43006526) for VR.

Comment: Have you tried with another videos? Some times is the codec, other times is the resolution or other weird thigs. I recomend you to try the default video that comes with the plugin in your 360 scene and look if it works in your device, if they do his job then is your video compresion. Maybe you can logcat your device and show us what the phone says.